# How to loop through JSON nested data in php?

Tags: php, json

I've this **JSON** data.

[image]

This is just a part of my file. The list is very long and coming from online website so I can't edit the **JSON** file.
Now I want to *loop* through using *foreach* and *echo* the name in friends *array*.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Search for json_encode and json_decode functions.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I used json_decode($jsondata, true) to convert into an array then used foreach to loop through the array. But I don't know how to skip in between elements and echo the nested value of following friends array.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$x = json_decode($jsonText, true);
foreach ($x['bio']['friends'] as $friend) {
    echo $friend['name'];
}
```

You first have to decode the json and store it into a variable. I named it $x, you can name it more suitable for your needs. The second parameter (true) is for decodibg data as array, not object.
Then you should check the data exists (this part is missing in my code). 
Third, iterate through the array.